# What is correct EL syntax to retrieve array element attribute stored as request attribute?

Tags: jsp, el

I have an ArrayList set as a request attribute for a jsp page.  The array list is populated by my servlet.  I use the array list to populate a drop down list on the page which functions correctly.  When the user selects an item in the dropdown, I want to use the index of the selection to retrieve a value from the corresponding element in the array list and display that value in another page element (named "limit").  I think I just can't get the EL syntax correct.

the dropdown in the JSP (which displays the options correctly):

```
<span>                                  

<select id="dropdown1" name="coveragelist" onchange="displaylimit(this)">
<option>Select coverage</option>
<c:forEach items="${coveragelist}" var="coverage">
<option value="${coverage.coverageCode}" />
<c:out value="${coverage.coverageCodeDesc}" />
</c:forEach>
</select>

</span>
```

the JS function:

```
<script>
function displaylimit(coveragedropdown)
{
var index = coveragedropdown.selectedIndex;
limit = "${requestScope.coveragelist[index].coverage.coverageLimit}";
document.getElementById("limit").innerHTML = limit;

}
</script>
```

The array contains Coverage objects which have attributes defined of coverageCode, coverageCodeDesc, and coverageLimit.

The index field does contains the correct value of the selected item in the dropdown (though I may need to subtract 1 from it - I'll have to check).  I just can't get the limit value from the specific element of the coverage list and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  It's probably something simple.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't mix and match EL (server-side) and JavaScript (client-side)

Comment: Ok, but that answer doesn't help me very much.  Can you be more specific as to where my error lies?  And perhaps point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You try to use a client-side runtime JavaScript variable `index` in a server-side resolved expression.

I think you will get JspException just trying to server that `<script>` fragment.

One way would be to build JavaScript array of `coverageLimits` on a server and embed it into `displaylimit` function

Here is one way of doing this:

```
function displaylimit(coveragedropdown)
{
  var index = coveragedropdown.selectedIndex;

  // Build the list on a server
  // I am not a JavaScript expert, so you may need to
  // do some escaping/quoting here
  var coverageLimits = [
    <c:forEach items="${coveragelist}" var="coverage">
      ${fn:escapeXml( coverage.coverageLimit )},
    </c:forEach>
  ];

  var limit = coverageLimits[index];
  document.getElementById("limit").innerHTML = limit;
}
```